# Why can't I create a folder in c:\folder\*\folder?

Tags: windows, mkdir

So I want to create a folder inside a 2nd level of subfolders.

So if I follow other example given here:

```
FOR /d %A IN ("e:\corporate folder\*") DO mkdir "%A\2015"
```

And change it to:

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\folder\*\folder1) DO mkdir "%A\Arq"
```

Do I need to add something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why can't I create a folder in c:\folder*\folder?

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\folder\*\folder1) DO mkdir "%A\Arq"
```

You cannot have wildcards (`*`) in the middle of a pathname.

Use the following command instead:

```
for /d %i in ("C:\folder\*") do mkdir "%i\folder1\Arq"
```

---

#### But I want to have a second wildcard

> The problem is that I need to put another (*) along the way so for example:

```
for /d %A in ("C:\folder*") do mkdir "%A\folder1*\Arq"
```

Then you need a second `for` loop.

Use the following command:

```
for /d %i in ("C:\folder*") do for /d %j in ("%i\folder1*") do mkdir "%j\Arq"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /d](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders.
- [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)

Comment: Thank you. Did not know that about the wildcards.

Maybe what i'm trying to do can't by done this easy but let's see.

The problem is that i need to put another (*) along the way so for example:  
  
for /d %A in ("C:\folder\*") do mkdir "%A\folder1\*\Arq"

I now know this wouldn't work but is there any way of doing it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JoãoSantos Answer updated